# How to play remote flv files

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I really cannot find a way to play remote [FLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) files via [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/).

Is it possible to do?

What I have got is here and I have tried the last version of JWPlayer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='mediaspace'><p>This div should have been replaced (by jwplayer.js)</p></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'http://www.influxis.com/btest/bsitz/apps/jwplayer/sample.flv',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '425',
    'height': '344'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That should work fine, do you have a link to where this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a really cool solution.

If you visit this site: http://www.osmf.org/configurator/fmp/

And just copy/past the code in order to test it

```
<object width="600" height="409"> 
  <param name="movie"
    value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
  <param name="flashvars"
    value="src=http%3A%2F%2Fosmf.org%2Fvideos%2Fcathy2.flv&poster=http%3A%2F%2Fosmf.org%2Fimages%2Fposter_cathy_fmp.jpg"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" 
     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" 
     allowfullscreen="true" width="600" height="409"
     flashvars="src=http%3A%2F%2Fosmf.org%2Fvideos%2Fcathy2.flv&poster=http%3A%2F%2Fosmf.org%2Fimages%2Fposter_cathy_fmp.jpg"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your flv to swf using any number of free online converters.  Not too familiar with JWPlayer, but there's a variety of other ways to embed flvs.  You can host it on youtube and link to that, you can add http://www.flvplayer.com/ to your website, or something like it.

Comment: You can also test with this file, it works fine - http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv

Comment: Thanks! But I need solution for JWPlayer. It plays local FLV files and perhaps should play remote FLV files via absolute URL.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/13/embedding-flash/ ? They have several approaches differing from yours, perhaps one will work over another?         Also, http://www.influxis.com/btest/bsitz/apps/jwplayer/sample.flv 404s, use Ethan's url to test.